# Where is the list of attached databases stored?

Tags: sql-server, database-internals

I know database instance names are stored in the registry in subkeys of `HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL` and the path to master.mdf is stored in `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\__InstanceId__\\MSSQLSERVER\Parameters@SqlArg0`. However, I don't see a table in master.mdf or a registry key where the names of the other attached databases are stored.

I know I can look in sys.databases for the databases. However, what I want to know is how to find this information out without sql server running. Is it stored in the master.mdf? In the registry? Can I get that information with a hex editor, [OrcaMDF](https://github.com/improvedk/OrcaMDF) or something else? How does Sql server know what databases to attach at startup?

Comment: They are stored in master. Why do you to get this information without SQL Server running?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith forensic analysis and pen testing.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't see a table in master.mdf ... where the names of the other attached databases are stored.

That would be [`sys.databases`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx). Running `sp_helptext 'sys.databases'` will quickly reveal what is the catalog table backing it:

```
CREATE VIEW sys.databases AS
    SELECT d.name, d.id AS database_id,
...
FROM sys.sysdbreg d 
...
```

To query `sys.sysdbreg` see [Using a Dedicated Administrator Connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't see sys.sysdbreg in OrcaMDF. I'll ask the author about it.

Comment: Update, that table [is actually in mssqlsystemresource.mdf](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190940.aspx). However, I still don't see that there.

Comment: @JustinDearing - It is in `master.sys.sysdbreg` as this answer says. If you look at the execution plan for `SELECT database_id,name FROM sys.databases` you can also see this. To verify this in the DAC you can find out the physical location with `SELECT *, sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(%%physloc%%) FROM sys.sysdbreg` then inspect those pages with `DBCC PAGE` for example.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks I understand that the master.sys.sysdbreg is the table in question. My question was how to see the files **without** SQL Server running. OrcaMDF, the tool I normally use to parse MDF files offline does not list that table.

Its obvious I'll have to patch OrcaMDF myself (if the original author doesn't beat me to it). The T-SQL you suggested will be quite helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

The user database information is stored within the master database.  Once the system databases are online SQL Server will pull that list and begin bringing them online.

As user databases can be physically created in any directory locally on the server (or UNC path with SQL Server 2012) there is no shortcut method of grabbing that list without SQL Server running.

You might attempt pulling the default path of database files from the registry as a start but again a database is not restricted to that directory.

**Update**

Based on your [last comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59985/where-is-the-list-of-attached-databases-stored/59987#comment108278_59985), you can get the list of user databases by reviewing the SQL Server error log files. These logs indicate the start-up sequence of the database engine and the user databases. The `SqlArg1` registry key has the path the ERRORLOG files will be written to and you can parse the specific files in the directory with this PowerShell command:

```
dir ERRORLOG* | foreach {Get-Content $_ | Where-Object {$_ -match "Starting up database"}}
```

The output returned should be similar to this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update about the log. I think I'll be able to get the actual list from mssqlsystemresource.mdf. However, that's another good forensic tool in case databases are being detached/reattached.